# Golang Reslicing Issue

Tags: loops, go, append, slice

I'm currently looping over a slice and removing the first element each time.

To do so, I am using the following code:

```
mySlice = append(mySlice[1:])
```

Everything goes fine for the first few iterations, but on later ones, some elements get removed and some get duplicated:

Before:

```
40.917
37.6384
41.2783
38.1481
```

After:

```
40.917
37.6384
41.2783
37.6384
41.2783
38.1481
```

I printed the `len` and `cap` of the slice for all iterations, but they seem to be decrementing by `1` for each iteration as expected.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the problem: It seems that even though I am simply passing my slice to another function to create a local slice, if I manipulate the local slice, my original slice gets affected as well (D'oh!).

Go Playground Link: https://play.golang.org/p/ca57tgusXD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

I needed to use the `copy` function instead of initializing my local slices using `:=`.

Go Playground Link: https://play.golang.org/p/N9RzHOibdI